# Stream from Windows Media Player to linux

Tags: linux, networking, streaming, raspberry-pi, audio-streaming

I'm trying to setup my Pi running Debian Wheezy to play music coming from any computer on the network using the `Play to` feature of the *Windows Media player*. The Pi is running headless, so a terminal package is **necessary**. Is this possible?

Comment: You can setup Windows Media Player to be a DLNA Server to stream to other devices. You could probably use the vlc-nox package to act as a DLNA receiver, but I haven't tried that before thouhg.

Comment: Yes this is true, but what I wan't to archive is that I don't have to access the Pi to start the music. If you enable remote control in WMP you can stream music to it using any other PC running WMP, without accessing the "reciever" itself.